# Trying to get a full URL without filename in PHP

Tags: php

I thought this would be simple but I can't seem to find a variable of `$_SERVER` array that has what I'm looking for.

Let's say my url is `http://example.com/subdirectory/index.php`  I want to get all but the filename - `http://example.com/subdirectory/`.

I know I could quite easily do this with some string manipulation, but I want to know if there's a var of the `_server` array that I'm just missing.  I've tried all of them to see what they give and I can get anything BUT what I'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There won't be one because it's not a useful attribute to track. If the current script is something other than `index.*` then it will not return the correct URL for the current script.

However, this might get you what you want:

```
echo '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

**Edit:**
Also, aside from installing the php.net online manual search tool for Firefox and setting it up with a search keyword (which will let you pull up the documentation on the `$_SERVER` global by typing something like "`php $_server`" into your URL bar), you should also know that `var_dump()` and `print_r()` lets you output the full contents of any variable, including arrays and objects. This is very useful for debugging.

Comment: But be aware, you should not assume that dirname() equals to the url path.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work, get a url like `http://magento.p111111.webspaceconfig.de/magento.p111111.webspaceconfig.de/`

Comment: @Stefan: You could try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as JackFuchs wrote. Perhaps you're using some form of URL-rewriting that has docroot specified one level up from where your wwwroot is served from. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I get two slash before direname

Comment: Watch out that dirname doesn't end with a slash unless it's the home page, where it's just "/" so if you do dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/folder"; you'll have 2 slashes in a row only if it's on the home page.

Answer (score 18):

In your case, string manipulation is the best solution.

For Example:

```
substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') + 1);
```

Comment: Or substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '\\') + 1); on a windows server

Comment: I don't think so Vincent. Since we're manipulating a URI here, NOT a windows file path!

Answer (score 9):

There are no defined variables for what you want.

You can use the code below to get the full base url:

```
// Base folder url
$myBase =  ( (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

but hopefully most times you won't require the full thing just use:

```
// Base folder server root path
$myBase = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Just be careful if you're using some kind of routes system (mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 3):

> I can't seem to find a variable of $_SERVER array that has what I'm looking for.

because it's fictional string, existing only in the browser's address bar.
It's parts being sent to server separated.

> I want to know if there's a var of the _server array

That's very easy to know. just `print_r($_SERVER);` really simple.

> I know I could quite easily do this with some string manipulation

yeah. the code you have to write is less than this question text.

but with some manual magic it can be reduced to just one function.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [dirname()](http://www.php.net/dirname) to get the path of a url.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me and seems to be a very clean solution.

```
$protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
$path = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, without `dirname` and respecting `http` and `https` is to use the old fashioned get path method ([source from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/3673659)).
Then check if the path ends with the fileextension ".php". If true, remove it from the path.

**Long version**

```php
$current_url_path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (substr($current_url_path, -4) == ".php") {
    // path ends with .php
    // split string to array
    $arr = explode("/", $current_url_path);

    // remove last array item (after the last / which is the file)
    $arrS = array_slice($arr, 0, -1);

    // join the array to a string
    $current_url_path = implode("/", $arrS);
}
echo $current_url_path;
```

**Shortened version**

```php
$current_url_path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$current_url_path = substr($current_url_path, -4) == ".php" ?
    implode("/", array_slice((explode("/", $current_url_path)), 0, -1)) : $current_url_path;

echo $current_url_path;
```

**Test**

This url: `http://localhost/comp-test/test.php` is returned as `http://localhost/comp-test`