# Setting links in an included top menu (HTML)

Tags: php, html, css

I use xampp on my local and I work on different projects. I generally use included top menus on web sites.

Directory Example:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\site1`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\site2`

In an included top menu I give links as

```
<a href="/site1/page1">Link</a>
<a href="/site1/page2">Link</a>
....
<a href="/site1/page7">Link</a>
```

But when I upload the site on a remote server, this links doesn't work. Because the root folder is not `htdocs`. The root folder is `site1` or `site2` whatever..

While I am working on `site1`, on my local, I have to set my default root directory to "site1" and I give links as

```
<a href="/page1">Link</a>
<a href="/page1">Link</a>
```

and it works for both (local-remote)

Question: How can I give the links in an included top menu without changing the local root directory.. I have tried as `../page1`. For main pages it worked but for sub pages didn't work..

Comment: if you start your link with / it moves to the root directory and goes on from there. To get the path from your active directory put ./ in.

In your example <a href="./page1">Link</a>

Comment: I didn't write in example but I have directories. With ./directory it works. When I click this link, all link becomes localhost/site1/directory/directory.......

Comment: then you might want to look at $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to get the base path of your php file and maybe navigate back in code (analysing output of variable)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602323/trying-to-get-a-full-url-without-filename-in-php   This link might help you as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a config.php file. On your remote sites this would just hold:

```
$path='/';
```

Put it in the same directory as your Menu file, in your menu file include the config.php:

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
```

and define links like this:

```
<a href="<?= $path ?>page1">Link1</a>
<a href="<?= $path ?>page2">Link2</a>
```

On your local machine edit the config file depending on the site you are working on:

```
$path='/site1/';
```

Comment: For the people who has the same problem: if you name the file as "config.php" it doesn't work. I couldn't understand the reason. I changed the name as "path.php" it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/page1"> Link</a>
```

Or
Create a config.php and define path like

```
$localhost = true // change this to false when you upload to server
if($localhost) {
  $root_path = 'http://localhost/site1/';
} else {
  $root_path = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
}
define('ROOT_PATH', $root_path);
```

And include this config.php in all your files where you needs to define the path

```
<?php
 include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/config.php");
?>
 <a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>/page1">Link</a>
```

Comment: I can't understand. I write echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/admin">'  The link is "localhost/site1/admin/localhost/admin"

Comment: Code: <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/admin"> Link: "localhost/admin" I need "localhost/site1/admin" This will work on remote server. But on local server I can't use