# PHP: Get URL except current file

Tags: php

I am trying to get the URL for the my webpage, but want to exclude the current file that I am working on. I have the following code, but it displays the fukl URL with the php file.

```
function getUrl() {
    $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
    $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
return $url;
```

This returns `http://127.0.0.1:80/proyect/register_form.php` and I want `http://127.0.0.1:80/proyect/`

Comment: `$url .= dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to have a million points to do anything, I was gonna mark this as a duplicate, but a mod can do it when they delete my post.

Since I also can't comment Mister Martin would receive my vote, his answer seems to be correct as it returns the filepath up until your actual file, sans the domain name.

```
$url .= dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
echo $url;
```

Also look here if you need more info, I found this one here 
[Trying to get a full URL without filename in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602323/trying-to-get-a-full-url-without-filename-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Use dirname function.

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/proyect/register_form.php';
echo dirname($url);
```

output

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/proyect
```